# How to get the name of a clicked item in an Inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, inventory

So, I need to get the name of a Custom Item that's in a Custom inventory using the InventoryClickEvent event. I've tried to get the Item Meta but it returns a NullPointerException. So, I made a little if statement to take care of the Item that's clicked not having Meta and the If statement fired. So, the Item doesn't have an Item Meta even though it has a lore and Display name. Please note that I don't deal with Inventories much so I'm kinda new to it. Also, I am setting the Item Meta with Display name and Lore in another class but I don't think that should affect anything. Here's my code for the InventoryClickEvent class.

```
public class clickEvent implements Listener
{
    private Files files = new Files();
    private KitPvP kit = KitPvP.getInstance();
    private Kit kits = new Kit();
    private InvUtils invUtils = new InvUtils();

    @EventHandler
    public void onInventoryClick(InventoryClickEvent e)
    {
        HumanEntity player = e.getWhoClicked();

        Inventory inv = e.getClickedInventory();
        ItemStack item = e.getCurrentItem();

        if (player instanceof Player)
        {
            if (inv != null && inv.getContents() != null && !inv.getContents().equals(Material.AIR) && inv.getName() != null && !inv.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
            {
                String name = ChatColor.stripColor(inv.getName());

                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kits: ") || name.equalsIgnoreCase("Kits:"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (!kit.getDataFolder().exists())
                        {
                            kit.getDataFolder().mkdirs();
                        }

                        File kFolder = files.getFolder("Kits");
                        if (!kFolder.exists())
                        {
                            files.createFolder("Kits");
                        }

                        File menu = files.getFolder("GUI Menu");
                        if (!menu.exists())
                        {
                            files.createFolder("GUI Menu");
                        }
                        if (!e.getCursor().hasItemMeta())
                        {
                            Logger.log("Clicked Item does not have Item Meta!");
                            return;
                        }

                        if (!e.getCursor().getItemMeta().hasDisplayName())
                        {
                            Logger.log("Clicked Item does not have Display Name!");
                            return;
                        }
                        String check1Name = ChatColor.stripColor(e.getCursor().getItemMeta().getDisplayName());
                        String check2Name = check1Name.replace(" Kit", "");
                        File gItem = files.getGuiItem(check2Name);

                        if (!gItem.exists())
                        {
                            Logger.log("Cannot find required Files!");
                            return;
                        }
                        String itemName = gItem.getName();

                        if (itemName.equalsIgnoreCase(check2Name))
                        {
                            kits.equipKit(player, itemName);
                            e.setCancelled(true);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to understand your problem as it needs for information but here goes.

1) I suppose that you use your event to carry over items etc and thus `e.getCursor()` resolves to an `Item`. Are you sure that the retrieved object contains meta when it's created, bundled in the event and passed around? My first though would be to check that one that the emitter of the event is creating the correct information.

2) Before the first if clause you do `e.getCurrentItem();`. This is a bit confusing since the return object seems to be an `ItemStack`. Your naming convention should be revisited. Same goes for the rest of the code. What is the `ItemStack` object holding and why can't you retrieve the item in question from there?

3) As mentioned in #1 check what the emitter of the event is doing. Most probably the `ItemMeta` are not sent due to this.

Also a quick hint. Avoid long method bodies like that. Try to breakdown your problem into smaller ones. This would make the debugging and maintenance process a whole lot easier. Finally avoid doing `String` equality check against constants the way you are. Instead of someVar.equals("someConstant") due "someConstant".equals(someVar). This is a quite nice trick into avoiding NPEs.

Comment: How I add the item Meta to the Item is read data from a file and then apply the meta to the item. I can see that the ItemMeta has been applied because when I view the Inventory, I can see that the Display name and lore etc.. has been applied successfully. Now, I'm sorry for my ignorance but I'm not sure what an emitter is in an event but I will research it. 

I applied a lot of what you have mentioned into my code and am going to test it. Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 0):

Just use this

```
if(e.getCurrentItem() != null && e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.INK_SACK){
String name = e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName();
}
```

Replace Material.INK_SACK with the target item

Comment: Well, I have items stored in a file. Then when the Inventory opens, it reads the file and fills the Inventory with the items. Also, I have kit creation commands so I can't check for each individual item.

Answer (score 0):

Like @Starmixcraft said, use this:

```
if(e.getCurrentItem() != null && e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.INK_SACK){
String name = e.getCurrentItem().getItemMeta().getDisplayName();
}
```

BUT replace

```
e.getCurrentItem().getType() == Material.INK_SACK
```

with

```
e.getCurrentItem().getType().equals(Material.INK_SACK)
```